# php error:You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got trouble with this php coding
when this file is launched, it just says
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 10' at line 1`

Can you help me figure out what is wrong?

```
<?php
  $open=mysql_connect('localhost','ID','PW') or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db('personal_info',$open);

  $tablename='writing';
  if($page=='') $page=1;
  $list_num=10;
  $page_num=10;
  $offest=$list_num*($page-1);

  $query="select * from $tablename";
  $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
  $total_no=$row[0];

  $total_page=ceil($total_no/$list_num);
  $cur_num=$total_no - $list_num*($page-1);

  $query="select*from $tablename order by number desc limit $offset, $list_num";
  $result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: select * from - add spaces

Comment: Indentation, line breaks and spaces are just as important as the code itself, if not more so, and you''ve just failed miserably.

Comment: I agree with @adeneo - this code is close to unreadable. Spaces before and after "=" and method blocks of if clauses on their own line (within their own {} block even better) will go a long way to making this maintainable to the developer who has to modify this code after you've moved on. Really, these days a few extra spaces aren't going to cost you anything.

Comment: thank you guys. I will accept your advice to become better programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two queries are:

```
select * from $tablename

select*from $tablename order by number desc limit $offset, $list_num
```

One possibility is that `number` is not a field in the table.

More likely, though, is the problem with `$offset`.  You have not given it a value, so your `limit` clause is `limit ,xxx`, and that is not allowed.

You do set the value for `$offest`, on the other hand.

```
$offest=$list_num*($page-1);
```

Hopefully, this should teach you to print out the actual queries being passed to the database.  The problem would then be obvious.

Comment: thanks. I simply made a mistake related to $offset

Answer (score 4):

```
$offest=$list_num*($page-1);
```

You've mistyped `$offset`, so the value is undefined. 
Also as @user4035 mentioned, add spaces around `SELECT*FROM`.

If these don't solve the problem try `echo $query;` rather than running the query, then post the results.

Also it's also good practice to break the query onto multiple lines. So

```
$query="SELECT * FROM $tablename 
        ORDER BY number DESC 
        LIMIT $offset, $list_num";
```

It helps readability, and also when debugging mysql errors, mysql will point to the line containing the error.

Comment: edit your answer and add your comment there and delete the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $open=mysql_connect('localhost','ID','PW') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('personal_info',$open);

    $tablename='writing';
    if($page=='') $page=1;
    $list_num=10;
    $page_num=10;
    $offset=$list_num*($page-1);

    $query="SELECT * FROM $tablename";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $total_no=$row[0];

    $total_page=ceil($total_no/$list_num);
    $cur_num=$total_no - $list_num*($page-1);

    $query="SELECT * FROM $tablename ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT $offset, $list_num";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
?>
```